# Unity auto-factory with params

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to inject an auto-factory which takes params, or even if this is possible with Unity.

For example I know I can do this:

```
public class TestLog
{
     private Func<ILog> logFactory;

     public TestLog(Func<ILog> logFactory)
     {
          this.logFactory = logFactory;
     }
     public ILog CreateLog()
     {
         return logFactory();
     }
}

Container.RegisterType<ILog, Log>();
TestLog test = Container.Resolve<TestLog>();
ILog log = test.CreateLog();
```

Now what I'll like to be able to do is:

```
public class TestLog
{
     private Func<string, ILog> logFactory;

     public TestLog(Func<string, ILog> logFactory)
     {
          this.logFactory = logFactory;
     }
     public ILog CreateLog(string name)
     {
         return logFactory(name);
     }
}

Container.RegisterType<ILog, Log>();
TestLog test = Container.Resolve<TestLog>();
ILog log = test.CreateLog("Test Name");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I can see how you can set up custom factories for creating instances in Unity, just can't seem to fund any clear examples for this example.

**Obviously** I could create my own factory but I'm looking for an elegant way to do this in Unity and with minimum code.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sorry to be one of those annoying people who answer their own questions but I figured it out.

```
public class TestLog
{
    private Func<string, ILog> logFactory;

    public TestLog(Func<string, ILog> logFactory)
    {
         this.logFactory = logFactory;
    }
    public ILog CreateLog(string name)
    {
        return logFactory(name);
    }
}

Container.RegisterType<Func<string, ILog>>(
     new InjectionFactory(c => 
        new Func<string, ILog>(name => new Log(name))
     ));

TestLog test = Container.Resolve<TestLog>();
ILog log = test.CreateLog("Test Name");
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that, but using constructor injection?

Comment: @Chesheersky the example above uses constructor injection.

Comment: I don't find "answering your own question" to be annoying, especially when it is useful :) Could you please explain this `RegisterType<Func<string, ILog>>(new InjectionFactory( ..)` code? It's not that obvious... I got it that it ensures that test.CreateLog("dsffads") is resolved, but **how?**, **why**?

Comment: The InjectionFactory method is how you register a lambda expression with Unity which defines how to construct the instance of type Func<string, ILog>. The lambda function is an anonymous function that constructs ILog from a given string.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @TheCodeKing works fine, but in most (possibly all?) cases could be shortened to the following:

```
Container.RegisterInstance<Func<string, ILog>>(name => new Log(name));
```

*(note that I'm using `RegisterInstance()` instead of `RegisterType()`)*

Since the `Func<>` implementation is already a kind of factory there's usually no need to wrap it in a `InjectionFactory`. It only ensures that each resolution of the `Func<string, ILog>` is a new instance, and I can't really think of a scenario that requires this.

Comment: The scenario is sufficient if function implementation does not need container instance.
If you have more possibilities of dependency resolution you can choose which one is correct by the `InjectionFactory` calling `c.Resolve<IDependency>(name)` where `c` is the container parameter. In `RegisterInstance` the container is not accessible as an argument.

Comment: Hey @PiotrKasprzyk sorry for a shameless plug but I implemented [a Unity extension](https://github.com/mykolav/unitycontainer-param-autofactory) that can, basically, take `name` from the factory-func's parameter and pass it to the constructor of `Log`, but resolve `IDependency` from the container (and pass it to the constructor too). Please take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615268/818321) for details.

Comment: @PiotrKasprzyk why just not capture `Container` instance from lambda? No need of container parameter whis way.

Comment: @Ghosthack I often do that, but you'll run into some `LifetimeManager` problems. For example, if you use a child container to resolve down the line, you'll still use the parent container that was capture at registration time.

Comment: @Tipx Agree, this is an issue. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 2):

[Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org) has [parameterized instantiation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b) to handle scenarios which need an auto-factory with parameters.

While [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) doesn't support this out of the box, it's possible to implement an extension which will work in a way similar to Autofac's.

A shameless plug: I implemented such an extension -- [Parameterized Auto Factory](https://github.com/mykolav/unitycontainer-param-autofactory).
It can be used in a way similar to this:

```
public class Log
{
    public void Info(string info) { /* ... */ }
    public void Warn(string info) { /* ... */ }
    public void Error(string info) { /* ... */ }
}

public class LogConsumer
{
    private readonly Log _log;
    private readonly string _consumerName;

    public LogConsumer(Log log, string consumerName)
    {
        _log = log;
        _consumerName = consumerName;
    }

    public void Frobnicate()
        => _log.Info($"{nameof(Frobnicate)} called on {_consumerName}");
}

var container = new UnityContainer()
    .AddNewExtension<UnityParameterizedAutoFactoryExtension>();

var logConsumerFactory = container.Resolve<Func<string, LogConsumer>>();
var gadget = logConsumerFactory("Gadget");
gadget.Frobnicate();
```

Please notice:

- `Func<string, LogConsumer>` is resolved from `container`, but it wasn't registered anywhere -- it's generated automatically.
- `Func<string, LogConsumer>` only provides the `string consumerName` parameter to `LogConsumer`'s constructor. As a result, the `Log log` parameter is resolved from the container. If the auto-factory func looked like this `Func<string, Log, LogConsumer>` instead, then all the parameters of `LogConsumer`'s constructor would've been supplied through the auto-factory.

Basically, the extension works like this:

1. It registers a so called `BuilderStrategy` in Unity's pipeline.
2. This strategy gets invoked whenever Unity is going to build a type's instance.
3. If the type to be built hasn't been registered explicitly and is a `Func` with parameters, the extension intercepts the instance building process.
4. Now we only need to dynamically create a `Func`of the given type which resolves its return type from the container and passes the `Func`'s parameters as a `ResolverOverride` collection to the `IUnityContainer.Resolve` method.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking for a fully typed factory interface (allowing for XML documentation and parameter names, for instance), you could use a [NuGet package](http://blog.pedropombeiro.com/typed-factories-a-la-castle-windsor-for-unity/) I created, which you can leverage simply by defining an interface for the factory, and then associating it with the concrete type you want to instantiate.

Code lives in GitHub: https://github.com/PombeirP/FactoryGenerator

Comment: Exactly what I need. Suggest you to add an example to your answer like here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/ in Dynamic Proxy section.

Comment: @Ghosthack   
I'd appreciate if you check out https://github.com/mykolav/unitycontainer-param-autofactory  
I believe its advantage over [FactoryGenerator](https://github.com/PombeirP/FactoryGenerator) is it doesn't require any code generation step. I. e., it generates factories dynamically in run-time. And doesn't even require to register a factory in the container. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615268/818321) for details.

Comment: @Nik Sure, looks awesome. Sorry, I've seen your comment just now. Soon I will need to replace default `IoC` of `MvvmCross` to `Unity` in a new project. I will try your extension for sure and provide some feedback. Thank you very much for it.