# Unity: Register and resolve class with generic type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, factory-pattern

I'm using Unity and try to follow to SOLID-principles as far as possible. Therefore all implementations only have dependencies to interfaces.

I have a collectionwrapper which looks like this:

```
public interface ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    int TotalCount { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create the instance of `ICollectionFactory<T>` with a factory. This is what I got so far:

```
public interface ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>();
    ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
    ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int totalCount);
}

public class CollectionWrapperFactory : ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public CollectionWrapperFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>()
    {
        var collectionWrapper = _container.Resolve<ICollectionWrapper<T>>();
        return collectionWrapper;
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int totalCount)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I know that using the container as a servicelocator is considered an anti-pattern, but I don't know any better way to solve this. If there's a better pattern for doing this I'm all ears... An alternative is using the Activator, but then the factory would need to know about the actual implementation of `ICollectionWrapper<T>`.

But the real problem is that I cannot register the ICollectionWrapper correctly.

```
container.RegisterType<ICollectionWrapper<T>, CollectionWrapper<T>>(new TransientLifetimeManager()); // Does not compile.
```

`T` may be any type. **I want to be able to create instances of `ICollectionWrapper<T>` without having to register every possible combination of `T`.**

Currently I only have one implementation of `ICollectionWrapper<T>`. But the point is that I really want Unity to be the only part that knows about the actual implementation.

```
[DataContract]
public class CollectionWrapper<TModel> : ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    public CollectionWrapper(IEnumerable<TModel> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    public CollectionWrapper(IEnumerable<TModel> items, int totalCount)
    {
        Items = items;
        TotalCount = totalCount;
    }

    public CollectionWrapper()
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<TModel> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> T may be any type. I want to be able to create instances of ICollectionWrapper without having to register every possible combination of T.

That's what register generics is for. Some IOC name the method as `RegisterGeneric` to make it self explanatory (autofac for example), but unity keep it [just an overload of `RegisterType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx).

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICollectionWrapper<>), typeof(CollectionWrapper<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Also note that your injectable is having multiple constructors. [That itself is considered as anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

If you fix the multiple construtor thing, above registration will work.

Comment: Great. That's exactly what I was looking for. I did not know about the overloaded method. Thanks! Do you have any suggestions regarding a better factory-pattern using Unity?

Comment: @smoksnes I'd use a [func factory like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3825270/2530848) If you don't like taking `Func<T>` dependency, you can abstract it in your factory. This way, you don't need a reference to your IOC container and thus eliminating the anti-pattern :)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
   container.RegisterType(typeof(IEmployee<>), typeof(Employee<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you're using **Configuration File** to **Register** your classes and interfaces, this can be helpful.

```
<alias alias="TModel" type="{namespace}.TModel, {assemblyname}" />

<register type="{namespace}.ICollectionWrapper[TModel], {assemblyname}" 
                mapTo="{namespace}.CollectionWrapper, {assemblyname}">
</register>
```

Here, I'm registering the class(**TModel**) that I will be using with my Generic Interface(**ICollectionWrapper**) and Class(**CollectionWrapper**).
And then I can resolve it through DI

```
    public class MyClass
        {
            private readonly ICollectionWrapper<TModel> _collectionWrapper;

                public MyClass(ICollectionWrapper<TModel> collectionWrapper)
                {
                            _collectionWrapper= collectionWrapper;
                }
        }
```