# Unity register generic type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

How to register generic interface as shown below:

```
public interface ISigQuery<T> where T : SigReadModel, new()

public class SigQuery : ISigtQuery<SigReadModel>
{
}
```

I tried to register as follows:

```
.RegisterType(typeof(ISigQuery<>), typeof(SigQuery))(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

I get error:

> Method name expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity: Register and resolve class with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334240/unity-register-and-resolve-class-with-generic-type)

Comment: @SelimYıldız No,  i tried already that:  .RegisterType(typeof(ISigQuery<>), typeof(SigQuery<>))(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()) then i get: The non-generic type 'SigQuery' cannot be used with type arguments

Answer (score 1):

Since `SigQuery` implements `ISigtQuery<SigReadModel>`, you will have to register it by that closed-generic version of `ISigtQuery<T>`:"

```
.RegisterType(
    typeof(ISigQuery<SigReadModel>),
    typeof(SigQuery),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Of you can use the generic `RegisterType` overload:

```
.RegisterType<ISigQuery<SigReadModel>, SigQuery>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to usage of [RegisterType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660923(v=pandp.20)#using-a-lifetime-manager-with-the-registertype-method) you need to change:

```
.RegisterType(typeof(ISigQuery<>), typeof(SigQuery))(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

to

```
.RegisterType(typeof(ISigQuery<>), typeof(SigQuery), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```